# Почему не вызывается класс из пакета?

Tags: python, импорт, path, package

У меня есть файл main.py рядом есть папка engine, в которой пустой `__init__.py` и модуль `starter.py` с классом `Starter()`

Вопрос, почему я не могу вызвать класс из starter.py?

Мой код main.py:

```
import engine
engine.Starter()
```

Мой код engine/starter.py:

```
class Starter():
   pass
```

Ошибка:

```
AttributeError: module 'engine' has no attribute 'Starter'
```

Объясните что я делаю не так.

У меня получилось достать класс только так:

```
from engine.starter import Starter
```

Но разве так должны вызываться пакеты? Разве я не могу просто сделать import и использовать его классы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В модуле `engine` нет класса `Starter`, он находится в `engine.starter`, поэтому Вы должны использовать это:

```py
from engine import starter
starter.Starter()
```

или это:

```py
import engine.starter
engine.starter.Starter()
```

Для сокращения импортов можете сделать так:

```py
import engine.starter as p
p.Starter()
```

Если же Вы хотите использовать всё, что есть в модуле, без указания родителя, то Вы можете сделать так:

```py
from engine.starter import *
Starter()
```